# Previnir que botão seja clicado duas vezes no android

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo de delivery, onde ao clicar no botão é disparado um pedido, acontece que está acontecendo um bug que mesmo com um código preventivo que inserir, ás vezes acontece de em milésimos de segundos ser disparado dois ou mais pedidos ao mesmo tempo, no caso ao clicar no botão que dispara, acredito que isso esteja ocorrendo devido a mais de um clique pelo usuário no botão (apesar que teria que ser bem rápido mesmo, pois logo depois aparece um dialog).

Eu estava tentando fazer com que isso não ocorresse colocando o seguinte código logo depois que o botão é clicado:

```
      //prevent two click the same time
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 30000) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Aguarde 30 segundos para solicitar uma nova corrida",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Comment: Já tentou desativar o botão depois do primeiro clique?

Comment: O botão tem que ficar ativo novamente depois de 30 segundos por exemplo...

Comment: Use `myButton.setEnabled(false);` ai depois de 30 segundos você habilita novamente.

Comment: Estou pensando se o dialog que existe para confirmar que tá causando isso... O processo é: clicou no botão, mostra um dialog perguntando se confirma o pedido, se ele clicar em sim novamente aí que dispara... @acklay

Comment: esse é um tipo de problema que Functional Reactive resolve muito bem. Tu faria um mapSwitch no evento de click com um debouce, e acabou o problema. Essa questão de duplo clique (ou n cliques) com requisição ao servidor, mesmo usando promises ou deferreds, são quase impossíveis de resolver de fato com vanilla js. Dá uma olhada na lib Rx. Quem sabe tu não adota no projeto. Ah, e isso sem alterar o estado do botão. Melhor ainda, sem manter estado nenhum! :) Abc

Answer (score 1):

Você tera que setar o método de desativação do evento click do botão, com isso você consegue controlar quando o usuário pode clicar ou não no botão, no seu caso ele pode clicar novamente após ser feita a solicitação do serviço, o código abaixo pode lhe ajduar a entender:

```
    onClick(View v){
        ChamarPedido();
    }


    private void ChamarPedido(){
        myButton.setClickable(false);
        //termine de fazer suas requisições e reeative o botão
        ClienteChamouPedido()
        myButton.setClickable(true);


    }
```

Comment: Seria melhor usar o método `setEnabled()` em vez de `setClickable()`.

Comment: @ramaral não vou discordar com você, mas poderia me dar o motivo ?

Comment: A razão tem a ver com o que o utilizador espera de um botão. Um botão inactivo, que não reage ao *click*, tem um aspecto diferente de um activo, que reage ao *click*. Ao usar `setClickable(false)`, o botão terá o aspecto de activo mas não reagirá ao *click*, o que pode confundir o usuário.

Answer (score -2):

O que eu faria seria o seguinte, quando o cliente clicar em fazer pedido ("finalizar pedido") eu criava um intent mandando ele para a tela ou um fragment de status de pedido.